# Ubuntu Installation on dual-Harddisk computer

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi, symbolic-link

I guess many might have asked this. i have a prob which i couldn't find answer for.

My laptop has **256G SSD** and **1 TB HDD**. Windows boots from SSD. I installed Ubuntu within 30GB space in the HDD, with partitons (12G for `/`, 8G for `swap`, 10G for `/home`. The **disks are GPT** based, with **UEFI based boot**.

The problem is the boot time is nearly 15 mins, from the GRUB to the Ubuntu login page. Windows does that in 10 secs. And it never turns off when i shut down from Ubuntu (last time took 20 mins, until i manually shut down).

I need  to know, if those are the necessary partitions. if not, please give me details on what partitions to include, and in what ratios.

I was reading about **symlinking** to SSD for faster systems, but have no idea about which partitions to symlink.

*I need Ubuntu only for another 6 months, so no need higher encryption and i can expand space upto 40GB for Ubuntu*.

Comment: Favour returned!  Question upvoted!  You're an 8 rep user already!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symlinking will not help you here.  Better to:

1. Boot a [gparted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) USB
2. shrink your largest Windows partition on the SSD by 12+8+10GB (=30 GB)
3. Install Ubuntu on the free space of the SSD.

Comment: hey. though the boot up was faster by using the previous comment procedure, ubuntu never turned off successfully. and finally it crashed my windows bootmanager [which i recovered and removed ubuntu now :( ]. i learned that the `swap` partition is been deprecated inthe latest versions of ubuntu. So, is it ok, if i make  12G for **root** and 8G for `/home` ? or should i go for `swap` too?

Comment: A swap partition is not deprecated!  The default has been changed to swap file because there is no difference in speed any more, so if you think you'll need to increase / decrease your swap frequently, go for a swap file.  If static: choose yourself what is most convenient to you for your use case @ShivaGovindasamy

Answer (score 0):

I guest you install root partition Ubuntu on HDD and boot in SSD. EFI Partition on HDD can't found root partition to start. 
There are two option for you:
1 - Re-install Grub boot on HDD and you laptop boot windows longer normal. Ubuntu will boot faster, you dont wait 15 ~ 20 minutes
2 - You re-arrange partition on your SSD and make one partition 20GB to install Ubuntu. This way make your laptop boot fastly and you have a best performance for WWindows. You dont need to make a partition for swap more

I have a laptop with the same Storage. I created 4 partition on SSD 250GB: EFI, WWINDOWS, BACKUP (of Windows) and UBUNTU. Another SSD 500GB, I have DATA (NTFS) for Windows User Folder, HOME (Ext4) for Ubuntu HOme and MEDIA (NTFS) for storage my media files. It boot very well and fast

Comment: So, based on what you said, i should create 20G for ubuntu root on SSD. and some space on HDD for /home. Is this correct?

Comment: @ShivaGovindasamy It makes sense to do that but ignore the first sentence in this answer as it makes no sense at all, the option 1, I mean. You only need one EFI partition and where the Ubuntu system partition is - very fast SSD vs very slow 5400rpm typical laptop HDD - is what will determine how fast it boots, certainly not where the bootloader is installed, even if in a different drive it makes no difference at all.